# Can I use DisplayTemplates in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, webforms-view-engine

I have a partial view (Company.ascx) in the DisplayTemaplates folder. I can render its content in another view using following structure `<% Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Company) %>`.

Can I render and somehow get the Html string from within a controller? I need that because I'm using Ajax which have to return html (Company structure) as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your controller action needs to return the HTML result of the execution of this display template you could simply indicate the path to this template and pass the required model:

```
public ActionResult SomeAjaxAction() 
{
    var company = FetchCompanyFromSomewhere();
    return View("~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/Company.ascx", company);
}
```

As far as rendering a view to a HTML string is concerned there are [some possibilities](http://www.joeyb.org/blog/2010/01/23/aspnet-mvc-2-render-template-to-string) but 
I wouldn't recommend you doing it.